# Linux ls command not showing any files

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, suse

One of my SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5 is in production. A few days ago for some workaround, we executed the below commands  :

```
cd /bin
#ln -s /usr/bin/env env
```

After that some command linux command like `ls`, `ll` are not showing contents.

```
 oracle@livesrv:~> cd ahf_soft/
    oracle@livesrv:~/ahf_soft> pwd
    /home/oracle/ahf_soft                    **<< -------- My Current working directory**
    oracle@livesrv:~/ahf_soft> du -sm *      **<<-- I can see some file in this directory**
    357     AHF-LINUX_v20.2.0.zip
    364     ahf_setup
    1       README.txt
    oracle@livesrv:~/ahf_soft> ls            **<< -- ls command not showing anything**
    oracle@livesrv:~/ahf_soft> ls -la        **<< -- this command also not showing anything**
    oracle@livesrv:~/ahf_soft> ls -ld
    oracle@livesrv:~/ahf_soft> ls -d
    oracle@livesrv:~/ahf_soft> which ls
    /usr/bin/ls
    oracle@livesrv:~/ahf_soft> ls /usr/bin/ls
    oracle@livesrv:~/ahf_soft>
```

please suggest me the solution for this problem ?

Comment: oracle@livesrv:~> type -a ls

ls is aliased to `_ls'

ls is /usr/bin/ls

ls is /bin/ls

ls is /usr/bin/X11/ls


oracle@livesrv:~> file /usr/bin/ls

/usr/bin/ls: empty

oracle@livesrv:~>

Comment: Please don't put relevant information in comments. [Edit] the question. So `/usr/bin/ls` is empty. But what is `_ls`? Please post the output of `type -a _ls`.

Comment: oracle@livesrv:~> type -a _ls
_ls is a function
_ls ()
{
    local IFS=' ';
    command ls $LS_OPTIONS ${1+"$@"}
}

Comment: Why is your `/usr/bin/ls` empty? Does `/bin/ls` work?

Comment: /bin/ls also not working.